# jar file execution works with -Dhttps.proxyHost option but does not work when I set the same proxy via export and then if I run java -jar sample.jar

Tags: java, linux, proxy, cmdline-args

I have a executable jar file which fetches gcp regions. This jar works when I issue it as below:
`java -Dhttps.proxyHost=web-proxy.in.softgrp.net -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -jar sample.jar`
This command works.
where web-proxy.in.softgrp.net is the proxy host.

But if I set the same proxy via export command and then issue java -jar sample.jar it does not work. Any reasons why?
`$>export https_proxy=http://web-proxy.us.softwaregrp.net:8080`
`$>java -jar sample.jar`
This is failing to fetch required info! I get SSL handshake exception for the same.

Comment: `web-proxy.in.softgrp.net` vs `web-proxy.us.softwaregrp.net` the proxies are different, try with the same

Comment: Where exactly does it say that an environment variable called `https_proxy` is supported?

Answer (score -1):

It worked when I set the proxy programmatically:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", getHTTPHost());
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", getHTTPPort());
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", getHTTPHost());
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", getHTTPPort());
```

instead of setting them via export command in cmd line and running the jar file.

Comment: Of course it does. That has exactly the same effect as  the `-D` argument you used before. The problem here is that you just made up a non-existent environment variable and wondered why it didn't work. Why should it?